# Using apply() to select specific variables by name

Tags: r, loops, apply

Ok, basically I have a dataset of households that looks like this:

```
household_data <- data.frame(
                                id = 1:4,
                                gender_component_1 = c(1,2,2,2),
                                gender_component_2 = c(2,1,1,2),
                                bread_winner      = c(1,1,2,1)
)
```

I want to construct a variable ('gender_bread_winner') which reports the sex of the breadwinner in the family - whether component 1 or 2 , which is reported in a separate variable as a numeric.

I've come up with the following loop:

```
var_max <- paste("gender_component", household_data$bread_winner, sep = "_")

for (i in 1:nrow(household_data)) {
  household_data$gender_bread_winner[i] <- select(household_data[i,], var_max[i])
 }
```

Unfortunately, the real dataset is huge and this solution is not at all optimal, I was wondering whether is it possible to do the same thing using apply or similar? I've not been able to though.

Thanks in advance

EDIT : Thank you all for your answers! In the end I found easier to use a score of ifelses like this:

```
dataset$sesso_max <- NA
dataset$sesso_max <- ifelse(dataset$max_percettore == 1, dataset$sesso_1, dataset$sesso_max)
dataset$sesso_max <- ifelse(dataset$max_percettore == 2, dataset$sesso_2, dataset$sesso_max)
dataset$sesso_max <- ifelse(dataset$max_percettore == 3, dataset$sesso_3, dataset$sesso_max)
dataset$sesso_max <- ifelse(dataset$max_percettore == 4, dataset$sesso_4, dataset$sesso_max)
dataset$sesso_max <- ifelse(dataset$max_percettore == 5, dataset$sesso_5, dataset$sesso_max)
dataset$sesso_max <- ifelse(dataset$max_percettore == 6, dataset$sesso_6, dataset$sesso_max)
```

Comment: I do not understand the rules for the creation of the breadwinner variable. When should the breadwinner variable be coded as 1 and when as 2?

Comment: (Nothing to do with the question): Your variable names are just too long. That is undesirable

Comment: Hi, bread_winner tells me whether component one or two is the breadwinner (i.e. highest income in the household). when bread_winner = 1 it means that it is component 1, when bread_winner = 2 it means is component 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are only 2 `gender_component` columns a simple `ifelse` would do.

```
household_data <- transform(household_data, gender_bread_winner  = 
        ifelse(bread_winner == 1, gender_component_1, gender_component_2))
```

This says that when `bread_winner` has value 1 take the value from `gender_component_1` or else take it from `gender_component_2` column.

---

For more than 2 columns we may use `max.col` as follows -

```
gender_cols <- grep('gender_component', names(household_data), value = TRUE)
household_data$gender_bread_winner <- household_data[gender_cols]
             [cbind(1:nrow(household_data), household_data$bread_winner)]
household_data

#  id gender_component_1 gender_component_2 bread_winner gender_bread_winner
#1  1                  1                  2            1                   1
#2  2                  2                  1            1                   2
#3  3                  2                  1            2                   1
#4  4                  2                  2            1                   2
```

Explanation for the answer -

`gender_cols` has all the columns that have `"gender_component"` in them.

```
gender_cols
#[1] "gender_component_1" "gender_component_2"
```

We create a matrix with row and column index to subset from the dataframe `household_data`.

```
cbind(1:nrow(household_data), household_data$bread_winner)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    1
#[3,]    3    2
#[4,]    4    1
```

This basically says that get 1st value from 1st row, 1st value from 2nd row and so on. This matrix is used to subset the data from the dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not sure I understand your code and how do I apply max.col ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `mutate()` function:

```
library(tidyverse)
household_data %>%  mutate(gender_bread_winner=ifelse(bread_winner==1,gender_component_1
,gender_component_2))

  id gender_component_1 gender_component_2 bread_winner gender_bread_winner
1  1                  1                  2            1                   1
2  2                  2                  1            1                   2
3  3                  2                  1            2                   1
4  4                  2                  2            1                   2
```